# Swift/iOS - Coremotion with phone orientation vertical

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, core-motion

I'm trying to use Coremotion to control a sprite in a game.

I have been able to get the sprite moving around using Coremotion. The problem is the x and y values received from Coremotion are in reference to the phone being in a flat horizontal position (i.e. on lying flat on a table).

When a user plays the game the phone will be held vertically with the screen facing the user. If they tilt the device away from them the sprite moves forward, if they tilt the device towards them the sprite moves backwards. If they tilt the phone left or right the sprite moves sideways.

How can I modify my code to reference the motion data from the phone being in a vertical position with the screen facing the user?

```
if motionManager.deviceMotionAvailable {
    motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.01
    motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){
        [weak self] (data: CMDeviceMotion!, error: NSError!) in

        var currentX = yLine.position.x
        var currentY = xLine.position.y

        // Translate yLine coordinates
        if data.gravity.x < 0 {
            destX = currentX + CGFloat(data.gravity.x * 1000)
        }else if data.gravity.x > 0 {
            destX = currentX + CGFloat(data.gravity.x * 1000)
        }

        // Translate xLine coordinates
        if data.gravity.y < 0 {
            destY = currentY + CGFloat(data.gravity.y * 1000)
        }else if data.gravity.x > 0 {
            destY = currentY + CGFloat(data.gravity.y * 1000)
        }

    }
}
```